# SQL Server record count discrepancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a program that lets users choose subsets of a given table (in SQL Server 2012, but hopefully I'm missing something and version doesn't matter). The program checks whether any subsets overlap, and also whether they (taken together) partition the entire table.

I have reached a situation that I really don't understand. I can't use real names or values, but this is the setup:

- I am looking at a given table (call it TABLE_X), and
- some particular predicates (say A, B, C and D) which I expect to be mutually exclusive, but not covering the entire table...
- I expect a query for the intersection of any pair of predicates, (e.g. WHERE (A) AND (B)) to return no records, and this is confirmed to be the case
- If the table has 5,000,500 records and the predicates' union has 2,000,000 records, I expect the complement of the union to have 3,000,500 records; this last point is where I've reached a problem

In the topic of record counts, here is what I have found:

- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X, I get (for example) 5,000,500 records
- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X where (A) or (B) or (C) or (D), I get 2,000,000 records
- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X where not ((A) or (B) or (C) or (D)), I get 3,000,000 records
- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X where not ((A) or (B) or (C) or (D)) or ((A) or (B) or (C) or (D)), I get 5,000,000 records

So I'm seeing the union of a predicate and its complement resulting in a lower cardinality than the cardinality of the table itself. This appears to defy logic.

Naturally, I asked myself whether NULL values were having some kind of an effect. Note that the predicates A, B, C and D are fairly simple boolean expressions all involving the same columns, say: c1, c2, and c3. What I found did not clarify matters for me:

- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X where not ((A) or (B) or (C) or (D)) and ((c1 is null) or (c2 is null) or (c3 is null)), I get 550 records
- if I select count(1) from TABLE_X where ((A) or (B) or (C) or (D)) and ((c1 is null) or (c2 is null) or (c3 is null)), I get 0 records

So I expected the two queries involving null checks to somehow produce the record count discrepancy (i.e. 500), however instead I get a new number (i.e. 550).

It's possible that I'm mishandling my null checks and therefore defeating myself, but I honestly don't know.

I've also checked that this table has a primary key, and I even did a count grouping by the primary key to confirm there were no duplicate records. There were no duplicate records.

One other oddity (this isn't my table) is that this table has a PK, and a clustered index, but the PK is not the clustered index (they're different- same columns, different column order...)

Therefore my question is: how can I determine why I am seeing record counts that appear to defy logic (as noted above)?

Please note: I know this site expects "research effort", however I don't even know what to search for- to me this is basic boolean logic. My attempt at helping myself was checking into the null value aspect, and that blew up in my face.

Comment: Suggestion:  Please take each of these cases you are trying and dump them into a separate table each.  Then you can do intersect/except to find the 500 rows that are at issue here.  You might be able to generate a minimal repro based on that work.  Perhaps there's a bug in SQL Server or perhaps it is just a bug in how you have written your query or perhaps ansi nulls is on/off and you didn't see that for some case (or some other setting).  Minimizing the repro will help you find the next step here.

Comment: Thanks Conor... I actually did that but using CTEs, forgot to mention it (result of UNION and also UNION ALL was 5,000,000; result of INTERSECT was 0)... would there be a difference between using CTEs and actual tables here?

Comment: yes there may be a difference.  CTEs are just views in SQL Server and the optimizer may be rewriting the broader queries to try to find more optimal plans.  What I suggested will split this up into different queries and help you find those 500 rows.  Then you can try to isolate out what is causing the difference more formally.  It will help you if you need to engage Microsoft Customer Support to get them to research it for you to see if there is a bug.  Please note that UNION distincts duplicate rows.  UNION ALL does not. Same for the INTERSECT/EXCEPT operators

Comment: I re-read your comment, noticed you suggested the EXCEPT operator which I hadn't considered. Selecting all except the union of the predicates and its complement yielded 500, the number I was looking for. I am going to investigate *why* these records have fallen through the cracks, but I feel like *identifying* them is almost answering the question... maybe post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting my comment as an answer per OP request.

There are several reasons this could happen:

- you could have a logic bug in your predicates
- There could be some session-level setting which is subtly changing how predicates are evaluated (ansi nulls on/off or similar)
- There could be a bug in SQL Server (does not happen very often, but if it's there then the SQL team will want to help get it investigated and fixed)

You stated in your post that you had tried to do CTE-based calls to look at the various patterns you were trying to narrow down the bug.  Based on the way SQL Server parses and compiles those queries, you should try a different approach.  CTEs are treated as views and are in-lined during compilation.  So, if there's a logic bug in SQL (third case), then adding CTEs would just repeat that same issue in your experiments and not necessarily help you narrow things down.

I am suggesting that you take the results of each of your individual tests and put them into temp tables.  Then I suggest you run those temp tables with EXCEPT ALL/INTERSECT ALL queries against the original query and the other patterns to narrow down the 500 rows for which you can not account.  If you can find those specific rows, you can likely make a smaller repro that will isolate the problem.  (If you were to engage with Microsoft Customer Support, this will help speed up that process by getting a minimal repro of your problem identified before calling them).

I hope this helps get to the bottom of your mystery.  Best of luck.

Conor

Architect, SQL Server

Comment: Using the EXCEPT clause allowed me to isolate the rows in question, and I found they all had NULL values for one of the columns in the predicates, confirming that I was bungling my NULL handling.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the issue and hopefully get it fixed!